# Windows 8 Task Manager RAM Usage Accuracy

Tags: memory, windows-8

The new Task Manager has a great UI in windows 8, however, there are some discrepancies in the data I can not account for:

Machine: 8 GB of total ram. (This is a physical machine, not a virtual)

The processes tab shows 45% of Memory utilized.  The listed process do not add up to 3.5 GB of RAM, but instead add up to 0.948 GB. There is no "processes for all users" option.

The performance Tab Shows:

In use : 3.6 GB
Available: 4.4 GB
Committed : 4.1 /9.2 GB 
Cached: 3.7 GB
Paged Pool: 376 MB
Non-paged pool: 135 MB

My reading of this says I have ALOT of "cloaked" processes running some where eating my ram.

**How do I interpret this data and how do I verify it?**

Comment: Try the Working Set column under Details

Comment: Thanks. Thoose numbers added up. Now to google what "working Set","working set delta", "private working set", and "shared working set". That does account for my RAM issue, but further makes reading and using this data less then helpful.

Comment: [Try RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx), tested and works in W8

Comment: [VMMap to dig deep](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) into memory processes

Comment: look if you have a high "non paged pool" usage. In this you have a driver leak and poolmon.exe is needed to get the causing driver.

Comment: I have the same problem but I was told I had a duplicate question so I'm asking here. The memory shown in task manager is 58% in the processes tab but doesn't add up to half my ram. This is true even in the details tab. Please help.

Comment: My question was marked as a duplicate but none of the comments or answers posted here solve my question. Can any of you lot help me? https://superuser.com/q/1591243/53724

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an explanation of the various terms, this two part presentation is a good start.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL405

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL406

Comment: Thanks +1 for actually addressing questions ( Readability of the information, not troubleshooting )