# Why does my memory usage have high percentage in task manager but the memory shown being used by each program doesn't add up to anything high?

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, task-manager

When I use Task Manager to see how much memory is being used, it says 76% memory. I have 8GB of ram. However when I add up all the memory being used by all the different processes, it doesn't add up to 8GB.

[image: memory in task manager not adding up]

As seen in the gif above, the memory usage shown by each program in Task Manager does not add up to 6GB of the memory I have out of 8GB. If around 75% of memory is used, then the memory usage of all the processes, should add up to 6GB, right?

What is going on and how do I fix it?

I see that similar questions have been asked, but the questions do not fit my use case as they are asking *different things* to what my question is asking and their answers are not helpful.

Comment: The answers and comments given in the question you want me to look at, it doesn't solve my question. I tried their suggestions and it didn't work.

Comment: The article referenced was 7 years back so I glance d just briefly.  Do you have (likely do) Show History fo All Processes in Options enabled?  Just a thought.

Comment: It's off. The option is greyed out so it won't let me turn it on. Even when I go to different tabs like details, performances and processes I still can't turn it on.

Comment: Thank you. That is set the same as me. One machine (little running) reconciles fairly well. This machine with VMware running does not reconcile because VMware allocates its own memory. Something like that may be happening to you.

Comment: But I'm not using a virtual machine. I booted straight into Windows.

Comment: I am not sure what is happening then. The machine here that is simple reconciles fairly well.

Comment: Try running Admin Tools, Resource Monitor. Open the Memory line.  (a) this shows more detail and in my case shows VMware usage better than Task Manager - better tool  (b) let it run for 30 minutes or so and see if memory on your machine is varying up and down. Resource Monitor is better for what you want.

Comment: It all adds up perfectly in Resource Monitor but not in Task Manager. I suppose the data is more accurate in Resource Monitor but Task Manager should not be giving false information. It doesn't feel that Task Manager is incomplete, it's more like inaccurate.

Comment: So that is the answer for you. Because Resource Monitor is a better detail tool

Comment: I'm going to ask about this on the official Microsoft Windows forum in the hope that microsoft fixes it.

Comment: I have three Windows 10 machines here: 2 x V2004 Production, and 1 x V2004 20H2 and Task Manager works the same way in all. So you are probably better off with Resource Monitor.